# Any way to ascertain iOS version of locked iPad?

Tags: ipad, ios

My iPad is 'disabled' and I need to know which version of iOS 8 it's running.

It's in the "iPad is disabled, connect to iTunes" state.

If I connect it to iTunes, it says "to allow access, please respond on ipad", but the ipad just says "connect to itunes."

Comment: First make sure you have the latest iTunes. iPad will be restored to the current iOS

Comment: I have the latest version of iTunes, does not make any difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to identify the iOS version from the Hello screen?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/390826/how-to-identify-the-ios-version-from-the-hello-screen)