# How to identify the iOS version from the Hello screen?

Tags: iphone, ios

I would like to identify the iOS version of my iPhone 6 from the Hello screen. Is there a way to tell the iOS version from the design of the Hello screen or from the MEID, IMEI or ICCID?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108057/discussion-on-question-by-gabriel-diego-how-to-identify-the-ios-version-from-the).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [checkra1n](https://checkra.in/) tool can identify the iOS version of the phone plugged into the USB port of the computer. It normally serves to jailbreak an iPhone in the Activation Lock for iPhones with iOS 12.3 through 13.4.1, but it can also display the version of iOS of the phone plugged in. It identified mine as 8.4.1. And this tool works both under Linux and macOS.

EDIT:
By the way, by using the Activation Bypass DNS browsing method, you can also check the version. I'm not going into details here about it, here is a Youtube tutorial describing it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jft96zWmpso

Answer (score 4):

Over the years since iOS was released, the opening **Hello** wallpaper which greets a user ready to set up the device has changed in several ways, most of them cosmetic. If each released major version had a subtle change to the **Hello** wallpaper, it would be easy to figure out which version of iOS was installed, but alas, the changes were few and far between.

Using [Apple Configurator 2](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12) you can see the installed iOS without going through any of the the setup steps:

[image]

Comment: I can't install this app on my computer. It says "Apple Configurator 2 can’t be installed on ... because macOS version 10.14.6 or later is required."

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Perhaps [this site](https://download.cnet.com/Apple-Configurator/3000-2651_4-75788201.html) has a version that will run for you. [This link](https://yellowfix.weebly.com/apple-configurator-27-dmg-download.html) may be helpful as well. Try them _at your own risk._

Comment: Thanks for the update! I already installed the checkra1n tool and it gave me the information I wanted by chance. I was looking for the iOS version exactly to check if it would work, but eventually I gave up and tried checkra1n directly. If it worked, I would know I had iOS 12 or 13, at least, but not only it failed, but it also told me which version os iOS I had installed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to [one of many iCloud DNS bypass pages](http://iclouddnsbypass.com/), fetch an IP address suitable for your region (for better performance, but any IP address will do)
2. Change your DNS setting to the IP address above.
3. Try rebooting the device and/or pressing "next" and "back" until iOS opens the web browser.
4. In the web browser, get to "open URL" page.
5. Find any UserAgent detector page online, then navigate to it on iDevice
6. Take note of the full user agent, as it will contain the iOS version. Alternatively, you can look up the exact UA string to find the (i)OS version